# Does Ledger Nano S has its own account?

Tags: ledger-nano-s

If I buy a Ledger Nano S, does it come with a built-in address? Does it create an address for me?

Answer (score 1):

When you configure a Ledger Nano S, it generates a 24 word mnemonic for you to write down and store in a safe place. The mnemonic is stored in the ledger's secure element and used to generate the private key securely.